# $\frac{2}{x_1+1} + \frac{2}{x_2+1} + \frac{2}{x_3+1} + ... + \frac{2}{x_n+1} \leq n$

Tags: inequality

Let: $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n>0$ and $x_1x_2x_3...x_n=1$. Prove that: $$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n \geq \frac{2}{x_1+1} + \frac{2}{x_2+1} + \frac{2}{x_3+1} + ... + \frac{2}{x_n+1}$$

I used Cauchy in LHS:

$$LHS \geq n$$ so I have to prove:

$$\frac{2}{x_1+1} + \frac{2}{x_2+1} + \frac{2}{x_3+1} + ... + \frac{2}{x_n+1} \leq n$$

and it can be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i-1}{1+x_i} \geq 0$$

I want to use Chebyshev but it was wrong!

Comment: What else have you tried? Can you prove the case $n=2$?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: I think the case for $n=2$ is easy, but induction is not easy with this!

Comment: The function $f\left(y\right)=e^{y}-\frac{2}{1+e^{y}}$ is convex with $f\left(0\right)=0$. Now apply Jensen’s inequality with $y_{i}=\log\left(x_{i}\right)$.

Comment: Can you use AM-GM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use AM-GM instead, here is a way:  Note that

$$\frac2{x+1}=2-\frac{2x}{x+1}$$
Hence the inequality can be equivalently written as
$$\sum_i \left(x_i+\frac{2x_i}{x_i+1}\right) \geqslant 2n$$
$$\iff \sum_i \left(x_i+1+\frac{2x_i}{x_i+1}\right) \geqslant 3n$$
By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{x+1}2+\frac{2x}{x+1} \geqslant 2\sqrt{x}$$
Hence it is enough to show
$$\sum_i \frac{x_i+1}2+2\sum_i \sqrt{x_i}\geqslant 3n$$
which follows from the AM-GMs $\sum x_i \geqslant n\sqrt[n]{\prod x_i}=n$ and $\sum \sqrt{x_i} \geqslant n\sqrt[2n]{\prod x_i}=n$.

Answer (score 2):

Well $\sum \dfrac2{x_i+1}\leqslant n$ does not always hold true (take $x_1=t^{n-1}, x_{i\neq1}=1/t$ and let $t\to \infty$), so we work with the original problem.

It is enough to show $f(x) = x-\frac2{x+1}-\frac32\log(x)\geqslant 0$, as the original inequality is the same as $\sum f(x_i) \geqslant 0$.

However $f'(x)=(x-1)\dfrac{2x^2+3x+3}{2x(x+1)^2}$, hence $f$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$ and increasing for $x>1$.  As $f(1)=0$, we must have $f(x)\geqslant 0$ for all positives, and so we are done.

Comment: Congratulations for the clever choice of $f$

Comment: Thanks! But can you use AM-GM please? The problem is in that section!